# Coded ui test builder of Visual studio 2013 not able to detect controls

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

Im fairly new to coded ui. I have been trying to automate  one of my company's product. While doing so i keep getting steps like "last action on list item was not recorded because the control does not have good identification property" in a combobox. 
Also there is window in the product made up xamdatagrid, xamtree etc. While recording these controls a blank line is being generated by the test builder in 2013, whereas test builder of 2010 generates "Click on "Unknown Name" window" for the same controls.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with one of my dropdown boxes. It turned out that because the data was being generated on the fly (the dropdown action was causing a bound function to fill the drop down), I could not access the automation id I set to each parameter. Instead I had to  revert to accessing each drop down item through its name.

The basic problem was that because each dropdown element was being generated dynamically, the object spy could not recognize it, since it was not generated until the drop down was clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. I am referencing a nuget package which calls a visual studio 12.0 reference, which no longer exists. Once I recompiled this package in VS2015, and dropped in the DLLs directly the problem went away! I now am going to get the owner to recompile & push via nuget.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, after a week of recompiling the package to get VS 2015 versioning of the test dlls, I realized that the Visual Studio 2015 versioned DLLs do not support VS Agents. IE. you cannot run a VS2015 test on the MS Test Lab.

I put in this hack, and got my tests to run again.....

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gopinath/archive/2015/02/27/test-agents-support-for-visual-studio-2015.aspx